# Displaying Active Subnav on Page Load (Bootstrap 3) - How to Prevent Close on Page Click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using jquery to display the active subnav on page load, which works fine. The problem is that when the subnav is visible and you click anywhere on the page, the 'open' class is removed from the dropdown, hiding the subnav. How can I prevent that?

Here is the jQuery:

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('open');
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown Link <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/link_one">Link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link_two">Link Two</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>          
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```js
$(document).on('click', ':not(#navbar a)', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#navbar').length == 0) {
    // if you did not click on the elements
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown open">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown Link <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/link_one">Link One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/link_two">Link Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="well">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh<br>
        helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This does prevent the subnav from hiding, however it also prevents some other features from working. Specifically, I'm using collapse (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to display some content and it stopped working when I added this code.

Comment: @pedalGeoff As you can see I updated the snippet with a collapse div and my snippet continue to work. The problem is: if ($(e.target).closest('#navbar').length == 0) { in other words which elements to discard from click to avoid menu closing. Let me know